# How to bitremine svn enable

Tags: svn, version-control, redmine

I had to install "Bitredmine"

Create a project and use SCM, subversion (SVN)

Can not be used, as shown below

[image]

red Exclamation mark message:
"SCM commands are not available. Check the settings on the page management."

How can I fix this problem?

Help me plz...

Comment: Have you checked the settings on the page management?

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario yep checked the settings page, all SCM(Source control management) red exclamation :(

Comment: Sorry but I'm not sure about what your question is. Do you need help to get your SCM settings right, or you know for sure that they are correct and Redmine is wrong?

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario ah.. Max 10.9 is used, Thank you answer

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario Thank you for your interest. Trying to use SCM SCM Setting Menu on all items marked with an error occurs.No part of this change, a special characteristic that the normal use of the Windows OS, the version installed on your Mac, but these symptoms occur.  So sorry you are not familiar with English.